# Как загрузить проект из gitlab на github?

Tags: github, gitlab, git-push

У меня есть проект на gitlab. Я его склонировал и хочу залить на GitHub. Но при попытке появляется ошибка. Я так понимаю что проект привязан к gitlab. Вопрос такой:
Как мне отвязать проект от gitlab, что бы я мог спокойно его загрузить на GitHub?

```
$ git push -u origin main
remote: Permission to Yamao93/adminpanel-laravel-vue.git denied to Yamao1.
fatal: unable to access 'github.com/Yamao93/adminpanel-laravel-vue.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: > Но при попытке появляется ошибка
Трудно однозначно угадать, какая ошибка у Вас появляется. Добавите её к вопросу?

Comment: PS C:\OpenServer\domains\admin-vue> git push -u origin main
remote: Permission to Yamao93/adminpanel-laravel-vue.git denied to Yamao1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Yamao93/adminpanel-laravel-vue.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Надо бороться с этой ошибкой. Признайтесь честно, вы ключи для гита - генерировали? а то вот хелп: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 3):

На гитлабе создаете **пустой** репозиторий. У вашего юзера должны быть разрешения на push в любые ветки.

На локальном компьютере делаете

```
git clone --mirror {адрес старого гитлаб репозитория}
```

Переходите в созданный каталог

Выставляете remote для пуша в новый репозиторий

```
git remote set-url --push origin {адрес нового репозитория в гитхабе}
```

Выполняете зеркалирование

```
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```

Все. На гитхабе полное зеркало репозитория со всеми бранчами и коммитами. Клонируете его себе обычным способом и работаете над проектом дальше

Comment: В Вашем ответе Вы предполагаете, что у пользователя уже настроен гит. Но, судя по комментарию к моему ответу, это не так

Comment: Но, вообще, я оценил детальность и точность Вашего ответа! То есть, если бы у автора вопроса не было проблем с авторизацией- то Ваш ответ был бы прямо тем, что ему нужно!

Answer (score 2):

я не претендую на полный ответ, но хочу обратить Ваше внимание на два момента:

1. Все, что "привязывает" проект к конкртеному git-репозиторию (и, вообще говоря, *образует* этот репозиторий, потому что git - это *распределенная* система управления версиями) хранится в скрытом каталоге `.git` - см. картинку

Если Вы этот каталог "грохните" - то у Вас останектся только текущая версия в виде файлов. Ни версий, ни истории, ничего.

[image: скрытый каталог]

2. А если Вы в github заливаете произвольный проект, не склонированный предварительно из гитлаба - ошибки не появляеется? Это я намекаю на то, что нужно проверить, что у Вас есть всё необходимое, чтобы пушить в гитхаб.
3. Наконец, самое главное. Если Вы хотите перенести из гитлаба в гитхаб (или наоброт) - там есть очень удобные встроенные средства переноса!

[image: импорт]

Comment: Только что проверил. Произвольный проект тоже не получается залить. Возникает такая же ошибка
remote: Permission to Yamao93/test.git denied to Yamao1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Yamao93/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: У Вас проблема с тем, чтобы нормально авторизоваться в гитхабе. Это делается про помощи ключей. Гуглите видео-как их сделать. Выше я привел ссылку на хэлп, там то же самое написано текстом